# why stat() return -1 even if file exists [RHEL 7.2]

Tags: stat

I am developing a module for Apache Server. In that, I am trying to read a file from path /tmp/_clusterMemberName/ using **stat(const char *filename, struct stat *buf)** function. My problem is stat() function  returning -1 even if file exists on the path. If I changed the file location from **/tmp/_clusterMemberName/** to **/opt/** then stat() function is working fine. Please help me to find out the reason.

Comment: After you call stat(), find out what value errno has and see if it fits one of the cases in the man page on stat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that `/tmp` is not accessible.

You need to look at the errno value that is returned by `stat`.  If it's `EACCES`, the reason for this is that the user does not have permissions to access `/tmp`.  If it's `EPERM`, the cause could be SELinux policy preventing httpd from accessing `/tmp`.  If you are using SELinux, make sure you're aware of the `httpd_selinux` manpage.

You can enable `httpd` access to `/tmp` with:

```
setsebool httpd_tmp_t 1
```

and make the change persistent with

```
setsebool -P httpd_tmp_t 1
```

Comment: thanks for input. On my machine, I am keeping SELinux disabled and getting errno value 2.

Comment: I want to share that, the same setup is working on the RHEL6 machine.

Comment: errno value 2 is ENOENT. are you sure you don't have a spelling error in `/tmp/_clusterMemberName`?

Comment: Thanks Paolo for the reply. I finally got the problem and its related to RHEL 7 security for /tmp directory. I have to disable PrivateTmp for httpd process in order to allow access of /tmp directory for httpd process.